# Workday Soap Requests Performance

Tags: java, soap-client, workday-api

I'm working on soap client that communicate with Workday Recruiting web-service.

I generated the client from the wsdl (I found here https://community.workday.com/sites/default/files/file-hosting/productionapi/Recruiting/v33.1/Recruiting.html).

Now, it's all works fine... but really really slow.

I tried to improve it with combination of using the generated objects in requests using WebServiceTemplate, but I failed to authenticate for Workday.

No salvation from searching the net.

My question - there is anyway to improve soap requests performance?

Comment: May be you can contact workday for support

Comment: @Smile Thanks for the idea, but I can't do that unfortunately

Comment: there is not much you can do than. Soap is very slow on its nature.

Comment: Additional WORKDAY DB information request, please. 
OS, Version? 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,  
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
df -i  for inode info by device, 
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.